chromatic number of a locally connected graph
Let $N$ be a number of nodes in a graph, where every node is connected to at most $l-1$ other nodes. Hence, the graph can have at most $l$ connected nodes. Can we find an upper bound of the chromatic number of such family of graph in terms of $N$ and $l$, using Big-O notation?

Obviously the graph has chromatic number at most $N$ if it has $N$ vertices.

There are known bounds to the chromatic number of a graph. In general, if $\Delta$ is the highest degree in the graph and $\chi(G)$ its chromatic number,
$$\chi(G) \leq \Delta + 1$$
If the graph is non-regular and connected, it can be proven that $\chi(G) \leq \Delta$.
In your case, we do not impose that the graph is non-regular, so all we can say is that $\chi(G) \leq \Delta + 1$. And since $\Delta \leq l -1$ it follows $\chi(G) \leq l$.
